# How to iterate a datetime list between dates increasing by 1 second in Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure

I'm trying to generate a datetime list in SQL Server with adding 1 sec to the `start_date` column with the same value of `stateDuration` column, for example if the `stateDuration` has 100 and `start_date` is '2022-09-29 07:29:16.000', then the new column (let's call it `new_time`) should start with the same datetime and loop 100 rows increasing by 1 sec.then round the new_time to the nearest 900 sec then group the data to be like the below.

The original data looks this:

```
userid  statuskey   stateDuration   StatusDateTimeGMT   EndDateTimeGMT
Abanoub.Sanad   available   4656    2022-09-29 07:29:16 2022-09-29 08:46:52
Abanoub.Sanad   available   24626   2022-09-29 10:12:26 2022-09-29 17:02:52
Abanoub.Sanad   available   9030    2022-09-29 17:18:23 2022-09-29 19:48:53
Abanoub.Sanad   available   33647   2022-09-29 23:04:07 2022-09-30 08:24:54
```

The expected data to see for the first row as an example:

[image]

**the comparison between sql and excel query on the same logic**

[image]

**the used query**

```
with cte1 as(
select userid,statuskey,stateDuration,[StatusDateTimeGMT]+ '02:00' as StatusDateTimeGMT,[EndDateTimeGMT] + '02:00' as EndDateTimeGMT,
interval= cast(floor(cast([StatusDateTimeGMT]+ '02:00' as float)*(96))/(96) as datetime),
interval_end_date=cast(ceiling(cast([StatusDateTimeGMT]+ '02:00' as float)*(96))/(96) as datetime)
from AgentActivityLog
where [StatusDateTimeGMT]+'2:00'>= '2022-09-28' and [StatusDateTimeGMT]+'2:00' < '2022-09-30' and StateDuration > 0 and userid = 'Abanoub.Sanad'),
cte2 as(
select userid,statuskey,[EndDateTimeGMT],[StatusDateTimeGMT],interval,interval_end_date from cte1
union all
select userid,statuskey,[EndDateTimeGMT],interval_end_date,dateadd(second,900,interval),dateadd(second,900,interval_end_date) 
from cte2 
where dateadd(second,15,interval_end_date)< [EndDateTimeGMT])
select userid,statuskey,interval,
[Duration]= case 
when interval_end_date<[EndDateTimeGMT] then datediff(second,[StatusDateTimeGMT],interval_end_date)
else datediff(second,[StatusDateTimeGMT],[EndDateTimeGMT]) end
from cte2
ORDER BY interval
```

Comment: What is the error in your approach?

Comment: Share your approach, desired output, some sample input data which violates the rule while following the approach

Comment: Please edit the question and share the details here

Comment: Code works fine for me. Please check this [script](https://dbfiddle.uk/oh2uuXzI). I have tried the same. There is no difference of one second as you shown in the post.

Comment: If error is due to rounding off the time, then use this 
`nearestdate= DATEADD( minute, ( DATEDIFF( minute, 0,start_date ) / 15 ) * 15, 0 )`  to round down and `batch_end_date=DATEADD( minute, ( DATEDIFF( minute, 0, DATEADD( minute,15, start_date ) ) / 15 ) * 15, 0 )` to round up.Go through this
[script](https://dbfiddle.uk/v8HpvRMj)

Comment: Many Thanks to you, really i can't find any words to thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input Table** is taken with one record as in below image

[image]

**SQL Script**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[src_table](
    [UserId] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [StatusKey] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [StateDuration] [int] NULL,
    [Start_date] [datetime] NULL
) ;
 
INSERT INTO SRC_TABLE VALUES('AAA','available','9030','2022-09-29 17:18:23'); 

    with cte1 as(
    select userid,statuskey,stateDuration,[start_date],
    nearestdate= DATEADD( minute, ( DATEDIFF( minute, 0,start_date ) / 15 ) * 15, 0 ),
    batch_end_date=DATEADD( minute, ( DATEDIFF( minute, 0, DATEADD( minute,15, start_date ) ) / 15 ) * 15, 0 ),
    total_end_date=DATEADD(second,stateDuration,[start_date])
    from src_table
    ),
    cte2 as(
    select userid,statuskey,total_end_date,[start_date],nearestdate,batch_end_date from cte1
    union all
    select userid,statuskey,total_end_date,batch_end_date,dateadd(second,900,nearestdate),
    dateadd(second,900,batch_end_date) from cte2 where dateadd(second,15,batch_end_date)< total_end_date)
    select userid,statuskey,nearestdate,
    [count]= case 
    when batch_end_date<total_end_date then datediff(second,Start_date,batch_end_date)
    else datediff(second,Start_date,total_end_date) end
    from cte2
```

**Output**

[image]